# Search for file by creation Time

Tags: c++, windows-7

I'm trying to write C++ code in windows to find a file by creation time, not by name of file.  Can't seem to find anything.  Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If your filesystem is indexed by the Indexing Service, you can query by creation date.

Comment: Some machines yes, Some machines no. In any case what did you have in mind? Is there an example? Thanks.

Comment: See http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch for some code samples. I've never used it myself, but it doesn't look too hard to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for files that are under 20 seconds old, searching the whole tree could take longer than that.

If you are looking for files that were created while your program is running, you could use [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(v=VS.85).aspx) to wait for notifications of file changes with a filter of either `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` or `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION`.

If your program is looking for changes that happened shortly before it started up, you could use the somewhat more complicated [change journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798(v=VS.85).aspx) API. You would want to use [`FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364586(v=VS.85).aspx) with a filter value of `USN_REASON_FILE_CREATE`.

Comment: If you search the whole file system, yeah that'll take longer than 20 seconds.  But if you're just searching under a particular directory tree that's not too big, it could be pretty fast.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm doing a search for a file that was just downloaded.  Is there a temp directory where a download always goes to before it's sent to a handler, or after?  Thank you.

Comment: @ME-dia: IE will put its cache files in the directory located read from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Cache`

Comment: Gabe, So you are saying that when a file is downloading it will go first to (above) before it ends up anywhere else on the hard drive?

Comment: @ME-dia: I'm pretty sure that's how IE handles it. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Thank you I will. Can I access this through DOS or windows explorer, or is it regedit.

Comment: @ME-dia: What are you trying to access through "DOS" (I'm assuming you mean the command prompt because DOS hasn't shipped a new version for 20 years)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FindFirstFile and FindNextFile to walk through directories, the file creation times are in the WIN32_FIND_DATA structure.

Comment: I found this....(WIN32_FIND_DATA.ftCreationTime). And I have the following.......
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(*.*, &FindFileData);
       if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
       {
          printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
          return;
       } 
       else 
       {
      _    tprintf (TEXT("The first file found is %s\n"), 
          FindFileData.cFileName);
 DeleteFile(*.*);
          FindClose(hFind);
       }
Basically I want to find a file that is newer than 20 seconds old.